# Why am I getting an Error 404 when I try to GET my css file?

Tags: html, css, directory

I am trying to import a css file in the same directory as my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
</head>
```

I believe I am correct in using ./ to go through my directory. I have also tried using ../

However, in my dev tools in chrome, I am getting this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely the link that's the error.
You will need to check your file path, is this project just simply on your desktop? Is it a ASP.NET app?
Depending on where/what project it is, you should be safe to use `..` to traverse up one folder

Answer (score 0):

It really depends how your directory folder is structured, but if you have your HTML and CSS files in the same folder, you can just use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">`  (note that there's no dot), then your html file will look in the root folder of your project, also make sure the name `styles.css` is the same as your css file

Answer (score 0):

Since you put the html file and the css file in the same folder, there is no need to use ./ or ../ because this step is written only if the css file is in another folder next to the html file

Answer (score 0):

open-source public files work best. So instead, go to https://gist.github.com and sign up if you haven't already, name the file (with extension, e.g. style.**css**), and paste your CSS3 code, click 'create secret gist', and click raw. copy the link and that will be your external CSS file.

-Good luck!